# Facebook graph API version expires

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed an application in C# that uses the FacebookClient class. The version if this FacebookClient is 7.0.6. First of all it is the first time i use the facebook graph api, so sorry if i ask basic questions :)

When i go to the application in developers.facebook i see a warning containing the following text:

[image: Warning message from facebook]

When i use the Get method on the FacebookCient class then i am not specifying any version. The Version property of the FacebookClient is null when i read it.

So my questions are:

1. Shouldnt the FacebookClient class automatically use the latest version of the graph API when no version are specified? It looks like it uses v2.0 even thoug v2.6 is the newest.
2. How can i make sure that it always uses the newest version possible?
3. Since i havent so much experience with the facebook api, what is the prefered way to deal with this?
4. Can i use a specific version by setting the Version property to e.g. "v2.6" or .Get("/v2.6/someCall")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the warning, there is an open bug for this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1634445133540643/

If you omit the version, it will use the API version of the App, not the latest version. It´s always the latest one if you create a new App, but it will not upgrade automatically.

Btw, there is an upgrade tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/

Comment: Ahh i see. I really didnt understand it either. Ok thanks for the clarification, it was a good help!

Comment: y i see. It says that the oldest supported version is 2.5 and 2.6 which i guess my application automatically uses.